# "https" for my site appears in Google search result

Tags: html, wordpress, google-search

I have a Wordpress site and when I search some keyword in Google, I found one of my articles appears, but the link starts with "https" (which would cause some warning page).

The link actually works with "http", and I never intend to use any "https" for any of my articles or the whole website.

Why do "https" links appear in Google search result for my articles? How do I avoid it?

Comment: google follows links from other websites. Perhaps someone linked at this article with https. You can't avoid it. But you can redirect the request to http what i doesn't recommend. Or buy a signed certificate.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Doing a quick google search for the following keywords will get you the information you seek: "https in google results"

Comment: I googled before I asked. There is no specific answer but one that is about "canonicals" and I don't quite understand why is it related to my question. I can also install SSL certificate if needed. That's why I am looking for help if any one has the experience to share.

Answer (score 0):

If HTTPS pages are showing in search results, then you can redirect them to HTTP and Google will adjust accordingly. However Google should not index HTTPS pages without a valid certificate. Can you provide more information?